# Changing date format in oracle

Tags: oracle

Help me with write the query in oracle to change date format from dd-mm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

| date |
| --- |
| 02-07-1995 |
| 03-04-1998 |

**Output**

| date |
| --- |
| 02/07/1995 |
| 03/04/1998 |

Comment: what is the date datatype and what is NLS_DATE_FORMAT

Comment: Date has no any format: it is a binary data. See [`date` data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B). Complementary to this: you cannot "see" the data that Oracle returns, because it returns binary data. What you see is what your **tool** shows to you. So only the tool is responsible for data display. I would say NLS formats should not be used implicitly: use explicit value for data formats in case of type casts (`to_date`, `to_char`, `to_number` etc). This is much clearer and the same for other DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

If that column's datatype is `DATE` (should be; don't store dates as strings into a `VARCHAR2` column), then:

```
SQL> create table test (col date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (date '1995-07-02');

1 row created.
```

One option is to use `to_char` function with desired format model:

```
SQL> select to_char(col, 'dd/mm/yyyy') result from test;

RESULT
----------
02/07/1995
```

In my database, if you just fetch stored data, you'd get this:

```
SQL> select col from test;

COL
--------
02.07.95
```

Altering the session and setting new format returns value you wanted:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select col from test;

COL
----------
02/07/1995

SQL>
```

---

If you stored those values as strings, then first *convert* them to valid `date` datatype values, and then apply `to_char`:

```
SQL> create table test (col varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('02-07-1995');

1 row created.

SQL> select to_char(to_date(col, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') result from test;

RESULT
----------
02/07/1995
```

Another option is to just replace the minus sign with a slash:

```
SQL> select replace(col, '-', '/') result from test;

RESULT
----------
02/07/1995

SQL>
```

---

The bottom line is: never store dates as strings.